# Как посадить такое меню на WordPress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Не могу посадить меню с сохранением стилей и вложенности элементов самого вордпрес.

Кто знает решение этой задачи?

```
<!-- <ul>
    <li class="current">
        <a href="index.html">Demos</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="about-style-one.html">Pages</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="about-style-one.html">About</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="shop.html">Shop</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="elements.html">Elements</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul> -->
```

---

Между вложенными ul находятся li и a без классов

Comment: А зачем вам нужно сломать WordPress и вывести без классов? Вы как потом будете узнавать в css, какой пункт меню отображает активную страницу, как отображать выпадающее подменю при наведении на родителя (для этого WP добавляет класс menu-item-has-children)?

Comment: <ul>
       <li class="sub-menu">
              <a href="index.html">Demos</a>
                 <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li>
                       <a href="index-agency.html">Creative Agency</a>
                    </li>. Плюс, в активном состоянии заглавная li должна иметь отдельный класс. Мне просто надо получить такую структуру через Walker, но никак это не выходит

Comment: Зачем вам walker? Выведите меню простым wp_nav_menu(), именно такая структура будет создана автоматически, с классами, отражающими текущую (активную) страницу.

Comment: Я через wp_nav_menu пробовал, но из-за вложенности генерируется моё меню, только без стилей

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_nav_menu#8-ispolzovanie-svoej-funktsii-dlya-postroeniya-menyu

Comment: https://codepen.io/dmitrij-rudenko/pen/XBMGZe Вот такой код адаптировал, но ничего не происходит и вордпресс просто вставляет свои классы, генерирует контейнер div  и вордпрессу норм